# How to set multi colors for value of TextInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change color of value in textinput when the "Done" button is pressed but I cannot set multi colors.

Like this : 
[image: Like this :]

this is my react native textinput component

```js
<TextInput 
    style={{
        borderColor: '#bdbdbd',
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: width / 1.5,
        height: height / 9,
        borderRadius: 10, 
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: this.state.fc,
        padding: 10,
    }}
    placeholder={'Enter here the text you can hear'}
    multiline={true}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ write: text })}
    value={this.state.write}
>
```